Economics.SE is closing, do we want some of their questions?
The Economics Stack Exchange beta will be closed down next week along with a bunch of other quiescent beta sites.  There's a movement building up (approved by the SE staff) to migrate as much of the content from these sites as possible to other, more active SE sites.
It seemed to me that some of the more advanced questions on Economics.SE might be on topic here, so I thought I'd ask for your opinions and help with getting these questions salvaged.  If you feel that this would be a good idea, here's what you can do:

Express your support for migrating these questions here, so that the SE folks can tell that the community here is (as I hope, at least) in favor of it.
Go through the list of questions on Economics.SE and look for ones that would be on topic here.
Collect links to the questions here, so that we can point an Economics mod at them before the site closes (example of such a list at SF&F meta).  Or you could just flag the questions for migration directly, but this way we avoid needless duplicate flags.

Note that we only have about a week to do this before the site will be closed.  The SE folks have said that they may be willing to extend the deadline to let active migration finish, but that applies only if the process has at least been started well before the deadline.
Ps. I've also posted about this on the Math.SE, Stats.SE and Money.SE metas, as the scope of all these sites overlaps at least somewhat with Economics.SE.  There's also a central post on the Econ.SE meta listing potential migration targets.
(Personal disclaimer: I've never been active on either Economics.SE or here; indeed, I only found out about these sites recently.  I just feel I should at least try to do something to help keep these questions alive and on the web, rather than just gathering digital dust in a compressed archive somewhere.)

I posted an alert in chat yesterday about how we're fairing vs the closed sites.

Some economics questions might be quantitative enough to be included in our community as it is linked to quantitative finance, but a fair amount of the questions are not directly linked to QF, so I'd say "yes" but only for the very quantitative questions.

Agreed. I'm up for taking the good quantitative questions so they'll have a home, even if they aren't necessarily about trading or asset pricing.

A list of questions we might want to have here:
https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/179/what-are-the-most-useful-sources-of-economics-data
https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/139/why-is-an-inverted-yield-curve-a-problem
https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/89/are-there-any-valuation-models-of-securities-that-use-hyperbolic-discounting
https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/154/what-are-the-major-philosophical-methodological-and-terminological-differences

These look like terrible questions. They are (1) free data online, (2) a rookie question, (3) broad appeal for a model, and (4) "what is econometrics". No way would I want this stuff on our site.

I think those questions are no worse than some of the still-open questions on this site, and it would be a shame to lose them.  Why not take these questions, I say.

@chrisaycock Rookie question it may be, but it was a full day's lecture in my advanced-level business economics course in college, hence why I asked it. But you're not wrong; it's a fairly straightforward question and answer.

@Aarthi We're pretty loathe to allow undergraduate-level questions on here. Many first-year MFE questions also raise ire here as well.

@TalFishman I'm willing to merge the contents of #1 into our own canonical data question. Plus I guess we can take #3 since you answered it. #2 and #4 don't look appropriate at all.

@chrisaycock I totally understand; I guess my larger point is that graduate econ students have written papers about yield curves through the ages. From my perspective, it wasn't inherently a UG level question. But, this is your site and you know it better than I do. :) I'm not wanting to argue semantics, promise!

@chrisaycock I agree #4 is not really appropriate to this site, but I say why not take #2.  It's really no more rookie than some other simpler questions on this site, IMHO.

@TalFishman Very well.

Thanks for the lively discussion. I was only browsing the questions rather quickly, maybe one of the regulars could do a more thorough job of it.

I'm one of the moderators on Economics.SE ..l I think there seems to be concensus to transfer 2, so will do so.

#3 seems to enjoy reasonable consensus too, so I've flagged it for migration.
